# Selecting column location before modifying its data in Python Panda data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

Panda beginner here.

I have below dataframe

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column12 | Column13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | E | G | I |
| B | D | F | H | J |

I want to modify data if the column satisfy certain conditions. For example

If column.contains('2', case=False)

then I want to change the data value to 3

Expected result:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column12 | Column13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | E | 3 | I |
| B | 3 | F | 3 | J |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('2', case=False)] = 3
```

*NB. case does not matter for `2`.*

output:

```
  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column12 Column13
0       A       3       E        3        I
1       B       3       F        3        J
```